# Symbol with two outline colors - QGIS

Tags: colors, symbols, qgis

Is it possible to create this shape with two colors in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Is this "shape" a point, line or polygon? The idea is the same for each, but the exact implementation differs slightly.

Comment: It is a point, with white outline, then pink and then no color in the centre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this kind of effect, we can use multiple layers on the symbol selector interface. Add in another layer to the symbol (using the plus symbol in the bottom-left corner), set both layers to have a transparent fill and set the outline of the bottom layer to have a wider outline than the top layer. Then set the colours for the two layers accordingly, with transparency scaled down for the bottom layer. Here are a few screenshots, though I've used black instead of white to make it more visible on the symbol selector dialogue:

[image: Top layer screenshot]

[image: Bottom layer screenshot]

Note the "outline width" on the bottom layer is larger than that on the top, to let it show through. Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, it is exactly what I was looking for!